# Помогите преобразовать нативный JS в JQ

Tags: javascript

Крч, пытаюсь устроится на джуна верстальщика, прошел все задания, осталось одно не могу сообразить что от меня необходимо, js у меня в процессе изучения, поэтому и проблемы...

Вот дословно рекомендации от Тимлида после того как он увидел код

" Jquery лучше сразу использовать под все операции с dom для стандартизации и более простой поддержки"

А вот мой код

```js
document.querySelector('.second-button').addEventListener('click', function () {document.querySelector('.second-button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  document.querySelector('.animated-icon2').classList.toggle('open');
});

 



var x = document.getElementById("contain");
    x.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
    function myFunction() {
      var element = document.getElementById("nav");
      element.classList.toggle("open");
      
      x.classList.toggle("change");
    }
    document.querySelector('.second-button_two').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.querySelector('.animated-icon2_two').classList.toggle('open');
    });
    var x = document.getElementById("contain_two");
    x.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
    function myFunction() {
      var element = document.getElementById("nav");
      element.classList.toggle("open");
      
      x.classList.toggle("change");
    }
```

Я вообще хз, что надо сделать тут и как сделать, ± ещё понимаю что такое DOM и на этом всё... мои полномочия как говориться всё.. Спасите плиз

Comment: так это ты должен спросить Тилида что ему нафиг надо))  чем jquery в 2022 лучше нативного js

Comment: "более простой поддержки " --- ударь большой ладонью по лицу этого лида, т.к. можно с лёгкостью написать пять-шесть обёрток на нативном JS, которые будут легко использоваться (как пример nanoJS - https://vladocar.github.io/nanoJS/), а jquery уже стал как моветон и он, если что, тормозной, по сравнению с нативом

Comment: Уже последние лет восемь обычно делают наоборот — переписывают jQuery на нативный JS... Думаю, это намекает на то, что лучше поискать другую работу с более компетентными тимлидами)

Comment: Однако показанный код всё равно какой-то странный и, судя по всему, с ошибками

Comment: Предположу, что ваш тимлид имел ввиду, что в проекте, над которым вы работаете, используют jquery.

Comment: По сути почти всё что вам надо - это знать эти замены: `document.querySelector('...') -> $('...')`, `.addEventListener(...) -> .on(...)`, `document.getElementById('str') -> $('#str')`, `classList.toggle -> .toggleClass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего от вас хотя, чтобы вы просто всё на jq переписали. В вашем случае, судя по тому коду, что вы показали, в этом нет ничего сложного. Вот к примеру первый кусочек вашего кода на jq:

```js
$('.second-button').on('click', function() {
  $('.animated-icon2').toggleClass('open');
});
```

```css
.animated-icon2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: none;
  background: red;
}

.animated-icon2.open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>repl.it</title>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <button class="second-button">second-button</button>

  <div class="animated-icon2"></div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Мне в своё время в jq помогла быстра вникнуть книжка **jQuery in Action**. Хотя для тестового я думаю вам достаточно будет прочитать пару вводных статей по этой библиотеке. Плюс всё траблы по ней очень легко гугляться даже на русском.

По поводу того, что jq "моветон", "устарела", "сдохло" и т.д. - это вещи субъективные. На мой взгляд здесь ситуация аналогична с php, который каждый год подыхает, и каждый год выходит новая редакция языка.

На jq на данный момент много всего написано, многие ui библиотеки используют его под капотом, многие прогери (особенно на галерах) активно его юзают, так как он реально ускоряет процесс выполнения рутинных задач и помогает сократить объём когда в целом, тем более если фронт пишется без фреймворка под какую-нибудь cms.

Единственный кейс когда jq нежелателен, это как раз если фронт пишется под фреймворком, типа ангуляра. В этих случая это будет, скорее всего, говнакодом, никуда не деться.

**p.s.**

Когда пишите на jq не используйте в колбэках стрелочные функции, это чревато багами. Пишите через анонимные функции.